# YouTube video not playing, unable even press play

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having issues with YouTube videos not playing on mobile devices. Currently I have the main stage (where the video plays) and five videos thumbnails below. The initial video autoplays (and I believe autoplay is disabled on mobile, which is fine), and if you click one of the thumbnails, that video plays on the main stage. However, when the page loads, the first video doesn't play, or allows you to push play. It shows a frame of the video for a split second and turns black. If I click on of the other thumbnails, they play. And if I click on the first video, it plays. But on page load it doesn't.

Can anyone please help?

The code I'm using is straight from Google Developers YouTube section... which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the "normal" behavior of the api. The problem is caused of the requirement that on creating the player a video-Id must be supplied. So, when an invalid video-Id or a dummy string of 11 characters is given as the video-Id, obvious not a valid video, it will be skipped. If this is right, then you can file an enhancement here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label%3aAPI-YouTube , requesting a more nicer solution to avoid this behavior.

Or be sure to always supply a valid video-Id when creating the player.